# Which is the the most suitable C IDE for beginners?

Tags: c, ide

I've just started to learn C. I'm using Dev C++ but I don't like this. Are there any other programs I can use?

Comment: This question is quite subjective / open-ended. Please read our FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: There's no such thing : "the best C developper environment" there are only environments which suit you or not : you just got to test them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile C in Visual C++, this is a good IDE, especially if you are just starting.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-overview

Answer (score 0):

I really like eclipse & CDT, well i like eclipse for about anything

Answer (score 0):

For plain C I really like using Sublime Text 2. It's more a very advanced editor than an IDE though.